# Pandas: apparent type mismatch using apply

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Say I want to `apply` a function to **user_location**

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4139 entries, 2020-12-20 06:06:44 to 2021-01-13 04:45:10
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column            Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------            --------------  ----- 
 0   id                4139 non-null   int64 
 1   user_name         4139 non-null   object
 2   user_location     3282 non-null   object
....
```

Why am I getting a `TypeError` (*argument of type 'float' is not iterable*) doing

```py
def get_country(s):
    for country in pycountry.countries:
        if country.name in s:
            return country.name

d = df["user_location"].apply(get_country)
```

while `get_country('Some text about Canada')` works like a charm

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-50fde3ed5073> in <module>
      6 countries = [country.name for country in pycountry.countries]
      7 
----> 8 d = df["user_location"].apply(get_country)
      9 
     10 df["user_location"]

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4106             else:
   4107                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4108                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4109 
   4110         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-89-50fde3ed5073> in get_country(s)
      1 def get_country(s):
      2     for country in pycountry.countries:
----> 3         if country.name in s:
      4             return country.name
      5 

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

If `apply` really apply `get_country` element wise, why is it complaining about `float` not being iterable? I tried to set `convert_dtype=False` just in case but it did not change a thing.

Comment: Please share some sample data for this.

Comment: Object is a container that holds many things. `NaN` is a float, perhaps you have that to deal with missing values. If that’s the case you’ll need to add logic to deal with those null values since it’s a float and won’t have the same methods as say, a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe some of user_location got mixed with numbers?
Just force them `"if country.name in str(s):"`

Comment: This would be the most likely explanation. OP you could write a loop to check through the data frame and see which of its values are floats.